# Akka message passing not working after containerizing the akka.net application

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, containers, akka.net

I contenarized lighthouse and a akka.net application (batchProcessor) in linux containers. Below it shows both containers are up.
[image]

I am also able to connect to lighthouse from Pbm client in my local machine.
[image]

But batchprocessor is not able to connect to lighthouse(seed node). Hence, message passing between these multiple clusters is not working.
Here is the dockerfile for Lighthouse:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

ENV ACTORSYSTEM="BatchProcessingSystem"
ENV CLUSTER_SEEDS "[]"
ENV CLUSTER_IP "127.0.0.1"
ENV CLUSTER_PORT "4051"

COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/win10-x64/publish/ /app

EXPOSE 9110 4051
RUN dotnet tool install --global pbm 

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .

ENV CPE_ENVIRONMENT "local"
ENV TNS_ADMIN "C:\oracle"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Lighthouse.dll"]
```

And this is dockerfile for batchprocessor (akka.net application):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
ENV CLUSTER_SEEDS "akka.tcp://BatchProcessingSystem@127.0.0.1:4051"
ENV CLUSTER_IP "127.0.0.1"
ENV CLUSTER_PORT "9121"

COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/win10-x64/publish/ /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .

ENV CPE_ENVIRONMENT "local"
ENV TNS_ADMIN "C:\oracle"

EXPOSE 9121

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BatchProcessor.dll"]
```

Can anyone help me with this?What Am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in the lighthouse configuration.

```
ENV CLUSTER_SEEDS "[]"
```

CLUSTER_SEEDS variable should save the same value for all members in the cluster including the seed nodes(lighthouse in your case).
Also, I would recommend to configure logging for debugging purposes as it described [in documentation](https://getakka.net/articles/utilities/logging.html). Akka .net write detailed log of cluster initialization, it might be very helpful in investigation.

Also it's unclear for me that you configure docker file for lighthouse. As i know lighthouse already has an image and all you need is to setup environment variables(ACTORSYSTEM, CLUSTER_IP, CLUSTER_PORT, CLUSTER_SEEDS) at start. You can read about this [here](https://github.com/petabridge/lighthouse).

I hope this helps.